# Database name based on subdomain plus standalone domains

Tags: dns, cloudflare

First I'll give you all some background information about my web app.

So at the moment users sign up for my service, and pick a subdomain to use. Each user has their own database which holds their information. The registration script also sends a request to Cloudflare's API which creates an entry for their subdomain:

All subdomains forward onto the AWS elastic beanstalk EC2 instance I have setup.

In my PHP I extract the subdomain from the host and use that to access the database, so that each user accesses their database via their own subdomain.

This works fine but I have been asked to setup a standalone domain where one of my users would like to use his own domain instead of the subdomain.example.com like everyone else.

Therefore, how can I route their dns into my web application, and detect which subdomain / database they want to use?

I have seen some articles on a map table etc but I couldn't find anything which fits my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would still be creating a sub-domain. The user can create a CNAME record pointing their domain name to the sub-domain. From there, if the request comes in as customerexample.com, you can do an internal rewrite and change it to sub.myexample.com using an .htaccess file if necessary. That way, you do not have to rewrite your code to accommodate such a simple exemption. Cheers!!

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying. Would I manually have to update the .htaccess file, so you know which standalone domain maps to each subdomain?

Comment: Yes. You can also make this an option where a user can clicks a check-box and enter the domain name and you automatically create the .htaccess entry. I like simple hands off solutions. ;-) That what happens when you become a lazy programmer!

Comment: Okay. One thing is that I just tried with no .htaccess file, eg pointing mydomain.com at subdomain.example.com and it worked without any config, until cloudflare moaned about internal CNAMEs (not a problem). Is there any way to make this a premium feature, I was hoping for this to only be available if you have a higher plan than the standard one most people will use? Eg store host maps in a database table?

Comment: You can possibly use a wildcard sub-domain reference to break domain name only access unless you specify an exception. For example, if not domain name AAA.com, if not domain name BBB.com, if not domain name CCC.com, if not sub.myexamplesite.com, then sub.myexamplesite.com. Or something like that. It would take a bit of discovery to figure it out.